# How to count frequency during specific time period

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'ID': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3],
'TIME': ['2010-01-01 01:01:00', '2010-01-01 01:05:00' , '2010-01-01 01:24:00', '2010-01-01 01:27:00', '2010-01-01 01:33:00', '2010-01-01 01:34:00', '2010-01-01 01:35:00', '2010-01-01 01:37:00', '2010-01-01 01:38:00', '2010-01-13 05:52:00', '2010-01-13 05:53:00', '2010-01-13 05:54:00', '2010-01-13 05:58:00', '2010-01-13 06:04:00', '2010-01-13 06:14:00', '2010-01-13 06:25:00', '2010-01-13 06:24:00', '2010-01-13 06:26:00', '2010-01-13 06:27:00']
})
```

I want to find all IDs appearing more than 3 times within 2 hours and their highest frequency within 2 hours.
My code is:

```
df_4 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'COUNTS'])
for time in pd.unique(df['TIME']):
   time = pd.to_datetime(time)
   df_2 = df.loc[(df['TIME']>=time) & (df['TIME']<= (time + timedelta(hours=2)))]
   df_3 = df_2.ID.value_counts().rename_axis('ID').reset_index(name='COUNTS')
   df_3 = df_3.loc[df_3['COUNTS']>=3]
   df_4 = df_4.append(df_3, ignore_index=True)
df_5 = df_4.groupby('ID').max().COUNTS
```

but the loop takes too long. Could anyone help me to do it faster, please? Thank you.

Comment: The current example does not work because `'>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this.

```
df_4 = df.assign(dummy=1).pivot_table('dummy','TIME','ID',aggfunc=sum).sort_index(ascending=False)
df_4 = df_4.rolling('2h').sum().reset_index().melt('TIME', value_name='COUNTS')
df_4 = df_4.loc[df_4['COUNTS'] >= 3, ['ID', 'COUNTS']]

df_5 = df_4.groupby('ID').max().COUNTS
```

[image]

The main logic behind my code is using pandas `.rolling('2h')` function. However, I needed to do some processing before using rolling `.rolling()`.

First, I had to pivot your table first and set `TIME` column as an index in descending order.

In order to pivot your table, I had to add a dummy variable (because that's `.pivot_table()` will return an error if I don't. Note: the dummy variable I used is `1` and the sum of 1 = counting.

Now the table is pivoted and `TIME` is set as the index, I applied the `rolling()` function.

Afterwards, I unpivoted the table using `.melt()`, filtered the table, and finally applied your `groupby()` function.